# XBox 360 wireless controller for windows

Tags: controllers

I have a Windows 7 pc, and i installed the driver of microsoft Xbox controller. If I only use 1 controller can i use it without the receiver?

Answer (score 1):

**No, you cannot do this**

It must be a WIRED controller, like the one shown [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003ZSN600)

The cable on the xbox 360 wireless controllers is merely for charging, it doesn't pass input from the controller.

Comment: It is worth noting that you *can* use a wireless controller if you buy the special kit that Microsoft made for PCs, but this is expensive and honestly not worth it when you can get a wired controller for $25 or so.